# Include not working

Tags: android, android-layout, include

I try to set this as the layout of my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<include layout="@layout/map_activity_base" />
```

If I use `@layout/map_activity_base` instead of including it, it works. The reaseon why I don't do that is because you can't include content of layouts for small screens in layouts for large screens but I need the content of `@layout/map_activity_base` in different layouts.

The Error I get is

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11383): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.l_one.app.achileo/de.l_one.app.achileo.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class include  
[...]  
E/AndroidRuntime(11383): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class include  
[...]  
E/AndroidRuntime(11383): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.include in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/de.l_one.app.achileo-1.apk]
```

So it seems that android thinks `<include />` is supposed to be a `View` but that only happens if I use `<include />` without any surrounding `View`

So is it possible to use `<include />` without any surrounding `View` and if not what is the best way to achieve what I want?

Btw: I don't know if it matters but this is the content of a library project.

edit: map_activity_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/listHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/listHeader"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<View android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#333"
    android:layout_below="@id/listHeader" />

<de.l_one.app.map.base.POIListView android:id="@+id/poiList"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#cccccc"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poiList"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="@string/googleAPIKey" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/cmtryNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cmtry_txt_view_back" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/navigate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/cmtryNameTextView"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cmtry_txt_view_back"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/navigate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need put "include" inside the root view at least. Something like following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...

   <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

...
```

/>

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `<include/>` can't be defined at the root of the layout. If you really need to start with an include, a better way is to use a `<merge/>`:

file fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    the <merge/> tag must be the root element
    while it actually defines an xml include.
-->
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- insert some layout here -->

</merge>
```

file activity_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- then the <include/> tag can then reference it, while merging. -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/fragment_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: updated the xml/comments a little, because I was struggling (and got the merge working like this).